# Fetching array from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to make a page for re-sending the activation mail to the a members of my site who have not received it.
I'm not able to fetch the required data from `mysql`.
This is what I have tried -

```
$act = mysql_query("SELECT activate FROM users WHERE email='$mail'");
```

where `users` is the table name, `activate` is the column name from which data is to be fetched.
The email address of which the code is to be fetched is stored in `$mail` and `email` is a column name in the table.

I want to fetch the data from the column `activate` and row which is same as the row in which the value of `email` column is same as the value in `$email`.

This is the output I am currently getting - `Resource id #11`

While the correct output must be something like - `55445513`

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you need to pass that resource to `$row=mysql_fetch_array($act); $row["activate"]` will give you the result

Comment: Are you using `php` for front end? If so please retag for `php` as well..

Comment: and usual blurb about the deprecation of mysql_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$act = mysql_query("SELECT activate FROM users WHERE email='$mail'");
$act_array = mysql_fetch_array($act);
```

You can then reference $act_array for your array element results.

Comment: This, and for viewing the array you could use print_r($act_array);

Comment: I am getting the output as Array ( [0] => 848526751 [activate] => 848526751 ) but i need the output to be just 848526751

Comment: print_r shows you the whole array in a neat way. JUST USE $act_array['activiate'] to display JUST the number.